# Nested Dictionary, values of one sub-dictionary gets duplicated across all even if specified

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, behavior

### Some context

This dictionary describe specific eateries at different blocks. The nested dictionaries are the food elements and the overall rating for them

`ckDict` looks like:

```
[
    "808": [
        "Carbohydrate Texture": 6, 
        "Carbohydrate Quantity": 3
    ], 
    "826": [
        "Carbohydrate Texture": 6, 
        "Carbohydrate Quantity": 3
    ]
]
```

In the context of this question, `ckBlk` is constant as it is part of a parent loop.

### The problem

In the main loop, I printing `ckBlk` for every iteration, it does not change.
After finishing with the debug loop, I end my whole program. (for debugging)
This means `ckBlk` does not get changed during runtime.

However, when I print from debug loop, you can the values from the first `ckblk` I print overflows into all other `ckblks` ( I initialized `ckDict` to have all the blocks and questions already)

I even tried replacing `ckBlk` in `setArr(arrCounter).ckDict(ckBlk)(fdCat_qnType) = CInt(Left(fdVotes(1, fdVotesCounter), 1)` to "808" which is my first `ckBlk` and others are still affected (testing with block "826")

`808` and `826` are blocks, with the question inside questions and the relevant rating
`setArr` is an array of `ckDicts`

### Code

```
For Each fdCat_qnType In setArr(arrCounter).ckDict(ckBlk)
    Debug.Print ("ckBlk: " & ckBlk & " | Qn: " & fdCat_qnType & " | Value: " & CInt(Left(fdVotes(1, fdVotesCounter), 1))) ' IMPORTANT FOR DEBUG
    Debug.Print ("826 before insertion: " & setArr(arrCounter).ckDict("826")(fdCat_qnType))
    setArr(arrCounter).ckDict(ckBlk)(fdCat_qnType) = CInt(Left(fdVotes(1, fdVotesCounter), 1))
    Debug.Print ("826 after insertion: " & setArr(arrCounter).ckDict("826")(fdCat_qnType))
    Debug.Print ("808 after insertion: " & setArr(arrCounter).ckDict("808")(fdCat_qnType))
    Debug.Print ("")
    fdVotesCounter = fdVotesCounter + 1
Next fdCat_qnType
```

### Output

```
ckBlk: 808 | Qn: Main Protein Taste | Value: 1
826 before insertion: 0
826 after insertion: 1
808 after insertion: 1
```

Comment: Can you give a [mcve] of the issue please? Along with some example data. With just this code we are not able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I second the motion and agree with @Pᴇʜ.  This is too difficult to read and understand, perhaps even more difficult than implementing the code. Maybe later somehow when I have nothing to do, I'll be back and try to understand it again.

Comment: How is the dictionary built, is it from json ?

Answer (score 2):

Found out the problem!
Because my nested dictionaries are generated dynamically,
when doing e.g. `dict[parentDict][subdictX] = subdict`
it passes the reference pointer to subdictX instead of the actual value.
So this means that the solution is to re-set the subdict
`Set subdict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`
whenever I declare subdict to be the value of subdictX